Does free radical addition of HBr to alkenes form multiple products or just one?
I came across the following question:

Find the total number of possible products that are formed by the free radical addition of HBr to 3-methylhex-2-ene in the presence of a peroxide.

I know that an anti-markovnikov product forms, but is it exclusively that or can a markovnikov product (albeit with very minimal yield) form as well?

I think the formation of the Markovnikov product is negligible but not completely impossible
